# How to prove this centering inequality

Tags: real-analysis, probability, random-variables, normed-spaces

When X is a random variable, please prove that
$$
\|X-EX\|_{L^2}\leq\|X\|_{L^2}
$$
It might be trivial, but I'm stuck on it.Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you know $EX$ exists?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\mathsf{E}[X-\mathsf{E}X]^2=\mathsf{E}X^2-(\mathsf{E}X)^2\le \mathsf{E}X^2.
$$